# Datatables - passing one data of the selected row to a modal

Tags: datatables, modal-dialog, row, selected

I have a datatable that has an edit button on each row. When I click the edit button, a  function opens a modal to display the data of the selected record.
Initially, I just want to get the id(which I referred to as PID) of the selected record. However according to my code, I am not sure how to extract the value passed. I kept on getting undefined response.

Please advise on any errors in my code or is there a better way to do this.

Thanks

```
    select: true,
ajax: {
    url: "people-grid-data.php", 
    type: "POST", 
},

columnDefs: [{
    "targets": [3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9],
    "visible": false,
    "searchable": true
},
],
columns: [
    {
        "width":"2%",
        "render": function (data, type, full, meta) {
           return    "<button type='button' class='btn btn-xs' data-toggle='modal'  data-target='#editPersonModal'>Edit </button>";
        },
    },
    {
        "data": "PID",
        render: getImg
    }, 
    {
        "data": "PID"
    }, 
    {
        "data": "personName"
    },
    {
        "data": "PeopleRemarks"
    }       
],
"order": [
    [2, 'asc']
]
```

});

$('#editPersonModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (data, type, full, meta) {
    console.log("Data ID---"+data['PID']);

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have a button in my grid , you open your modal with this, using data atributes

```
render: function (data, type, row) {<a data-info="' + row.IdUser + '" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalGridTable" ...
```

in row.IdUser i have my id. now when i click in $('#modalGridTable').on('show.bs.modal', function (event)...

```
        var button = $(event.relatedTarget);
        var id = button.data('info');
        var data = Grid.ajax.json().data;
        function getDataJson(IdUsuario) {
            return data.filter(
                function (data) {
                    return data.IdUser === IdUser;
                }
            );
        }

        var result = getDataJson(id);
```

so you can read this example:

```
result[0].Phone
```

Comment: Wilmer, code example provided works great and is just as I had wanted.